# Was the "beep beep" transmitter on G'Kar ever mentioned again?

Tags: babylon-5, babylon-5-the-gathering

In the pilot episode of *Babylon 5*, "The Gathering", G'Kar comes out as the villain of the piece, and Sinclair pretends to slip a nanotechnological location transmitter in his drink as "insurance" to make sure he won't threaten the safety of Babylon 5 again. Garibaldi, at least, is also in on the plot, and Sinclair tells him that there was no actual transmitter:

As far as I can remember, this is never brought up again, neither by G'Kar nor Garibaldi (who both remain in the show for all five seasons) nor anyone else. Of course, G'Kar later undergoes massive character development, becoming an ally and friend to the Babylon 5 command staff rather than an antagonist, so I wonder if they ever came clean with him and revealed that there was never any transmitter.

Is this dangling plot point ever resolved, either in some episode that I forgot about or in extra material like JMS interviews?

Comment: I assumed the Narn scanned and probed him, told him they'd not found anything and that was an end to it.

Comment: @Valorum See the conversation between Sinclair and Garibaldi at the end of the linked clip. The idea seems to be that they keep on scanning and probing him indefinitely; they don't find anything but there's no simple end to it.

Comment: Eventually they'd conclude the Sinclair was joking or lying. Who knows how aliens think, though?

Comment: G'kar, having run a con or 2, would've eventually figured it out.  In a while. Long enough for things to settle down at least.

Comment: I *think* I read an interview with JMS where he said it was supposed to come up again later, but someone sent him a speculative script with that as a plot-point, so he was unable to.  Or something similar.

Comment: Sinclair explains to Garibaldi that there isn't a transmitter, but that the Narn will subject G'Kar to all sorts of unpleasant probes and scans until they are *sure* there isn't one. We are left to assume that this is what happens.

Comment: @JonB If you can find that interview again, it would make a great answer :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sadly it was in a journal that I read twenty years ago, so it's unlikely I'll be able to find it, which is why I put it as a note rather than as the answer.